# How to split and write the output of a linux command to multiple files of a specific size?

Tags: linux, bash, command, output, writetofile

How can I split and write the output of my command in Linux bash, to multiple (text) 5M files (number of files does not matter)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pipe its output to `split`.

Example:

```
$ my-command-name-here | split -a 3 -b 5g - myFile.
```

will produce files of 5GB having the names `myFile.aaa`, `myFile.aab`, `myFile.aac` a.s.o.

Use `-l` instead of `-b` to produce files with the specified number of lines instead of bytes.
Read `man split` or the [online documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/split-invocation.html).

Comment: Good answer! +1. Question - how many files will be produced in this case?

Comment: The option `-a` tells it to use the specified number of letters (small caps `a` to `z`) to generate the names. Using `-a 3` provides `26*26*26` unique file names.

Comment: @axiac Vey good answer, Can I also get files with numbers like :myfile 1, myfile 2?

Comment: Use `-d` for numeric suffixes instead of alphabetic.

Comment: @axiac I keep getting this error that I am not sure why: my command| split -a 3 -d -b 500M /directory for output             split: invalid option -- 'm'
Try `split --help' for more information.

Comment: The last two parameters of `split`, after the options, must be two file names. The first is the input file, the second is the output file (it's just a prefix, `split` will append letters or digits to generate the names of the files it generates). Because you want it to get the data from standard input, the name of the input file is `-` (i.e. a minus). It seems you forget it.

Comment: @axiac Can I also zip the files on the fly directly while writing?

Answer (score 1):

Another answer that adds the `--filter` option to support the request from [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27131074/how-to-split-and-write-the-output-of-a-linux-command-to-multiple-files-of-a-spec/27131300#comment42764098_27131300):

```
my-command | split -b 500m -d --filter='cat > $FILE; zip -m $FILE.zip $FILE' - myFile.
```

This tells `split` to use the command provided in parameter `--filter` to produce the files.

The command dumps the data it receives at `stdin` into the file `$FILE` (the variable is set by `split` with the name of the file it computed) then asks `zip` to move the file into the archive `$FILE.zip`.